# sidekiq to cancel list to scheduled jobs

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

I have several scheduled jobs running like this:

```
MyWorker.perform_at(3.hours.from_now, 'mike', 1)
```

I am wondering, if later, say an hour later, I feel like I want to cancel this job, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 16):

I've recently written a bit of code to handle this, it's available in my branch of the sidekiq-status gem. You can view it, or use it here:
https://github.com/Robinson7D/sidekiq-status

(You would have to use that as the `git:` information in the gemfile, currently, until the main fork of the project implements this)

To use it, first you store the job_identifier:

```
job_identifier = MyWorker.perform_at(3.hours.from_now, 'mike', 1)
```

And when you wish to destroy it you call the Sidekiq::Status.cancel method:

```
Sidekiq::Status.cancel job_identifier
```

**Edit:** since writing this post, my code's been accepted into the main fork of Sidekiq::Status - https://github.com/utgarda/sidekiq-status . You no longer have to use my fork. On Utgarda's fork you would trigger it by calling unschedule, instead of cancel:

```
Sidekiq::Status.unschedule job_identifier
```

Further: you can also delete jobs using the standard Sidekiq gem as explained here: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API (though for their methods you require the unix-timestamp of when the job is scheduled for - you cannot delete with only the job's id; if you wish to delete a job without the timestamp, the Sidekiq::Status method may be right for you).

However, instead of the ways they outline in the wiki I would recommend something along the lines of `Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new().delete(unix_timestamp, jid)` if you want to delete just one job.)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know Sidekiq has no way to cancel a schedules job for now. I wrote a service which lets me cancel my scheduled mails because of that. But you cancel jobs fairly easy with redis commands:

You get schedules jobs like this:

```
schedules_jobs = $redis.zrange "schedule", 0, -1, {withscores: true}
```

Then you get an array of jobs and you pick one job and and cancel it like this:

```
$redis.zrem "schedule", schedules_jobs[0]
```