# Sidekiq: Count the number of available threads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I'd like to count from the Rails console the **total number of available Sidekiq threads/processors.**

`threads != workers`

```
Sidekiq::Workers.size doesn't work
```

Comment: this other answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683222/are-there-console-commands-to-look-at-whats-in-the-queue-and-to-clear-the-queue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `Sidekiq::ProcessSet#each`.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/api.rb#L719

```
Sidekiq::ProcessSet.new.each do |pro| 
  puts "I have #{pro['concurrency'] - pro['busy']} threads free"
end
```